# Append AJAX Output to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have done my research and I can't seem to find the appropriate answer.

Here is the problem. First off, this question may be broad. And I am new to ajax. I am using laravel and I have just created a controller which handles two dates `whereBetween` to find the result set and ajax is handling the get request. I am having two issues.

First being, I have no idea on how to append to my existing table. The other issue is a bit complicated. Currently i am using carbons `diffForHumans()` to display the time taken.

Also using if else statements. Here is how my current table looks like (this is looped from controller for sample data. this is not ajax):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Room Number</th>
        <th>Cleaned By</th>
        <th>Total Time</th>
        <th>Supervised</th>
        <th>Issues</th>
        <th>Cleaned</th>
        <th>View</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($clean as $cleans)
        <tr>

            <td>{{$cleans->roomnumber}}</td>
            <td>{{$cleans->users->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$cleans->roomnumber}}</td>
            @if($cleans->verified == 1)<td class="verified">Yes</td>@else()<td class="notverified">No</td>@endif
            @if($cleans->img1 || $cleans->img1 || $cleans->img1 == !null)<td class="verified">Yes</td>@else()<td class="notverified">No Issues</td>@endif
            <td>{{$cleans->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{route('starlord.show', $cleans->id)}}"><i class="lnr lnr-eye"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As shown above, i have used `with()` in my controller to get the users name using user_id column. And the `diffForHumans()`. Also some if else statements.

Here is my AJAX so far:

```
$(function() {
    $('.form').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data in value key pair using jquery serialize
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        // get the url we are posting to from the forms action attribute
        //var url  = $(this).attr('/admin/search');

        // process the form
        var search = $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: "search", // the url where we want to POST
            data: data, // the url where we want to POST, set in variable above
            dataType: "json", // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode          : true
        })

        // using the done promise callback (success)
        search.done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data);


            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();

    });//submit function

});//doc ready end
```

So how can I append to the above table and still maintain those `diffForHumans()`, if else statements and most importantly the user name using user_id column (relation)?

**Update (Controller):**

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $data =  $request->only(['from', 'to']);
    $data['to'] .= ' 23:59:59';
    $output = Clean::whereBetween('created_at', $data)->get();
    //return view('admin/search-test', compact('output'));

    //return Response($output);
    return Response::json(array($output));
}
```

Comment: Please show us your controller too

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz sorry. i have updated the question